# Package does not exist when using separate App as a dependency

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio

I'm trying to compile an App utilising a separate App as a dependency but when I compile referencing modules from this library I see several "error:package does not exist" and "error:cannot find symbol class" messages from graddle. The following are my two build files.

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        exclude 'resources.arsc'
        exclude 'classes.dex'
    }
}

dependencies {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'
    compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.+'
    compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:+'
    compile files('libs/crashlytics.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.2.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/libphonenumber-5.9.jar')
    compile files('libs/mobileservices-0.2.0-javadoc.jar')
    compile files('libs/mobileservices-0.2.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/stringtotime-1.0.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/urbanairship-lib-2.0.2.jar')
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:extra-abs:+'
    compile files('libs/FlurryAnalytics-4.0.0.jar')
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.3'
    compile project(':wheel')
}
```

Dependency gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "kankan.wheel"
        minSdkVersion 5
        targetSdkVersion 7
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

}
```

Can anyone help/experienced this before? Android Studio does not highlight any issues in the class and I can ctrl+click through to the packages referenced which seems to mean it is set up correctly...

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot have two gradle scripts using the `com.android.application` plugin at the same time. Change the dependency project to apply the 'library' plugin.

If that doesn't do it, change the targetSdkVersion of your dependency to that of your core project.

Comment: @Doge You mean `com.android.application`?

Comment: Yes, this is the new plugin name. When I originally wrote the answer the plugin was named simply 'android'

Answer (score 6):

The buildTypes section should not be in library build.gradle file.

Comment: I would +100 this if I could. Thanks.

Comment: Your suggestion worked for me however is there any explanation for it??

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Android library module as a dependency (i.e. mylib), then make sure in your app.iml file that you see the following line toward the end of the file:

```
    <orderEntry type="module" module-name="mylib" exported="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing min and target sdk to 11 and 19 according in dependency gradle-default config.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26062783/weka-in-android-studio-intellisense-works-but-compilation-fails)

But I got it resolved using @Doge's suggestion, 
I converted the dependency android project to library project.

Thanks.

Comment: But this error occurs in the library module, not the app module.  So why would it matter to convert your android project to library??

Comment: Your link was removed