# Android Studio with uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoView

Tags: android, photoviewer

I am using Android Studio 0.8.14, and I have included the module from https://chris.banes.me/2012/10/12/photoview-v1-1/ but it always show me

Error:(27, 29) error: package uk.co.senab.photoview does not exist

But within the program the import uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoViewAttacher; without any error.
That's puzzled me.

I have been trying to resolve this without any success.

[image: error: package uk.co.senab.photoview does not exist]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should check first: [Package does not exist when using separate App as a dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050097/android-studio-package-does-not-exist)

then - if this does not fix your issue you should create a dependancy of your library:

reference which helped me to solve this problem:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html

in this case you should add : [your-photo-library-name] dependancy for your main app in Project Structure Screen.

Hope it helps.