# Error:(25, 23) error: package org.apache.http does not exist after updating sdk tools to 23.0.0

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-sdk-tools

```
Error:(25, 23) error: package org.apache.http does not exist
```

after updating sdk tools to 23.0.0

Everything was working fine when it was version 22.2.0.

Its hard to figure out what went wrong. I spend a lot of time with googling, but didnt find anything useful. Someone pls help me. Thanks.

Comment: Did you check if the apache library is added to your path? In Eclipse - right click project - java build path

Comment: @Sipty am using android studio. so how can i check that.

Comment: Try the suggestions in this answer, I think they are related! :-) http://stackoverflow.com/a/26050273/2796939

Comment: Thanks for your effort @Sipty but that is not the issue i have.

Comment: W E T R I E D B O Y S :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32153318/httpclient-wont-import-in-android-studio  check this. :(

Comment: @Sipty its okay bro :)

Comment: I'm in the same situation. No more apache http client : http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/23/changes.html